# last and preceding month deductions

Tags: dax, daxstudio

I have 2 measures as seen below

```
Preceding 3 Month Revenue = 
var var1 = LASTDATE('Sales'[ShortDate])
var var2 = EDATE(var1,-2)
var var3 = calculate(min(Dates[FinancialPeriodNo]),Dates[ShortDate] = var2)
var var4 = calculate(min(Dates[CANUSAFinancialYearNo]),Dates[ShortDate] = var2)
var var5 = edate(calculate(min(Dates[ShortDate]),Dates[FinancialPeriodNo] = var3 && Dates[FinancialYearNo] = var4),-1)
var var6 = edate(var5,-2)
var var7 = calculate(min(Dates[FinancialPeriodNo]),Dates[ShortDate] = var5)
var var8 = calculate(max(Dates[ShortDate]),Dates[FinancialPeriodNo] = var7 && Dates[FinancialYearNo] = var4)
return
calculate(sumx(values('Sales'[ShortDate]),calculate(sum(Sales[RevenueGBP]))),FILTER(ALL('Sales'),Sales[ShortDate] <= var8 && Sales[ShortDate] >= var6))

Last 3 Month Revenue = 
var var1 = LASTDATE('Sales'[ShortDate])
var var2 = EDATE(var1,-2)
var var3 = calculate(min(Dates[FinancialPeriodNo]),Dates[ShortDate] = var2)
var var4 = calculate(min(Dates[CANUSAFinancialYearNo]),Dates[ShortDate] = var2)
var var5 = calculate(min(Dates[ShortDate]),Dates[FinancialPeriodNo] = var3 && Dates[FinancialYearNo] = var4)
return
calculate(sumx(values('Sales'[ShortDate]),calculate(sum(Sales[RevenueGBP]))),FILTER(ALL('Sales'),Sales[ShortDate] <= var1 && Sales[ShortDate] >= var5))
```

Which work fine, now I need to find the sum of revenue for the customers which contribute to the revenue in Preceding 3 Month Revenue but not in Last 3 Month Revenue and vice versa.

Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

No idea if this will work, but here we go...

```
Measure1 = 
  var preceding3MCustomers = 
    SUMMARIZE(
      'Sales',
      'Sales'[CustomerId],
      'Revenue', [Preceding 3 Month Revenue]
    )
  var last3MCustomers = 
    SUMMARIZE(
      'Sales',
      'Sales'[CustomerId],
      'Revenue', [Last 3 Month Revenue]
    )
  return
    SUMX(
      FILTER(
        preceding3MCustomers,
        NOT preceding3MCustomers[CustomerId] IN DISTINCT(last3MCustomers[CustomerId])
      ),
      [Revenue]
    )


Measure2 = 
  var preceding3MCustomers = 
    SUMMARIZE(
      'Sales',
      'Sales'[CustomerId],
      'Revenue', [Preceding 3 Month Revenue]
    )
  var last3MCustomers = 
    SUMMARIZE(
      'Sales',
      'Sales'[CustomerId],
      'Revenue', [Last 3 Month Revenue]
    )
  return
    SUMX(
      FILTER(
        last3MCustomers,
        NOT last3MCustomers[CustomerId] IN DISTINCT(preceding3MCustomers[CustomerId])
      ),
      [Revenue]
    )
```